# How to setup NupenGL and include it in a Visual Studio project

Tags: c++, opengl, visual-studio-2013, nuget

I need to setup Visual Studio with OpenGL for a class. I found a [site](http://in2gpu.com/2014/11/29/setting-opengl-visual-studio-using-nuget/) that explains how to install the NupenGL package through NuGet to get the OpenGL libraries and headers. I follow the instructions and see that everything gets installed to a packages/ folder in my solution folder, but absolutely nothing happens to my project that allows those files to be included.

What do I have to do to include the libraries and headers from the NupenGL package into my project so that it can build OpenGL code?

Answer (score 5):

Be sure that nupengl.core and nupengl.core.redist are listed in your packages.config (look for it in your Project-Explorer on the right).
In your project folder there should be also two nupengl folders inside the "packages" directory.

Then type `#include "GL` in your .cpp file. Intellisense should then show you the path of the GL directory inside your nupengl directory as a tooltip.
So just type

```
#include "GL\freeglut.h"
```

or

```
#include "GL\glut.h"
```

to use OpenGL-Functions in your code.